# How to find $p(t)$ when $m$ varies linearly with $t$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have a function $p(t)$ (position and time) defined by $$p(t) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{F}{m} \cdot t^2$$ when the mass is constant. This is derived from Newtons second law and by integration of the acceleration to get position. However my problem is a bit different. As time passes, the mass decreases linearly with time so that $$m(t) = m_0 - qt$$

How can $p(t)$ be calculated?

Comment: $d(t^2) = 2t\,dt$. Also note that it doesn't make sense to have the same variable inside the integral and as boundary values (eg. $\int_0^t \dots dt$).

Comment: It's hard for me to understand why, if $m$ is $m(t)$, then the result must be that integral. For me it would just be $p(t) = \frac{F}2 \frac1{m(t)}t^2$. Can you elaborate? Especially on why $t^2$ goes "inside" the $\mathrm d$.

Comment: How can **this** be calculated ? What do you mean ? You know the position as a function of time and you know the mass as a function of time. What is the unknown ? I don't think you are giving us the right problem statement.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The mass decreases as time passes. The mass isn't defined based on what $t$ is at $p=p(t)$. I might have been a bit unclear in the question.

Comment: You should have just said "the force is constant and the mass decreases linearly with time", then.

Comment: Updating the question to clarify now, thank you.

Comment: Hem, you didn't clarify anything. The first two misleading sentences are still there, as is the title.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you for reminding me of the title. My original problem is a bit more complex, and this question is very simplified, which is why, after simplifying the question a lot, it turned out to be a simple differential equation, not what the title originally stated (as Tom-Tom wrote in his answer). Now it is just a matter of rewriting my original equation as a differential equation. I guess I must learn how to express my problems in a more simple manner to be able to solve them more easily.

Comment: Newton's second law accommodates changing mass as well:   $ F = \frac  {d(m v)}{dt} = \dot m \; v + m \dot v $. This happens for a rocket whose mass reduces with time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly address such problem, you should go back to the differential equation. In that case, this would be 
$$ (m_0-qt)\frac{\mathrm d^2p}{\mathrm dt^2}=F(t).$$
Your question is not really clear about the nature of the force, so I will
consider two cases.

**Case 1:** $F(t)=mg$ where the acceleration $g$ is constant. 
$$(m_0-qt)\frac{\mathrm d^2p}{\mathrm dt^2}=(m_0-qt)g.$$
So the solution is again $p(t)=\frac12gt^2$. (Note for physicists: this is quite a natural outcome since the free fall is independent of the mass)

**Case 2** If the force is constant, you get
$$ \frac{\mathrm d^2p}{\mathrm dt^2}=\frac{F}{m_0-qt}$$
Integrating a first time, you get
$$\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dt}=\frac Fq\;\ln\frac{m_0}{m_0-qt}$$
and a second time
$$ p(t)=\frac F{q^2}\left[qt-(m_0-qt)\ln\left(\frac{m_0}{m_0-qt}\right)\right].$$

**Note**: I imagine, the first case is the one you are asked about, the second case is just for fun.

Comment: Thank you for such an in depth answer! The second case is the one I was trying to solve. I was just trying to solve the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: I have an object that is pushed by a force $F$. As time passes, the mass of the object decreases, so that over time the acceleration of the object increases. What I was thinking was that for an infinitesimal timeframe, the difference in $p$ is given by what is inside the summation in the question. So by letting $\lim_{k→\infty}$ I would expect to get the actual $p$.

Comment: I understood why you thought about the summation. The point is that as $p$ is the solution of a second order differential equation, it is not possible to use small increments in a simple way. You should actually use increments of increments, which indeed falls back to double integration.

Comment: The second case fails as $t\lesssim \frac{m_0}q\left[1-\exp(-c F/q)\right] $ because at this point the particle becomes relativistic and Newton's second law must be corrected.

Comment: Now I understand why the sum doesn't work. Since the time is squared, it increases much faster than the mass decreases, so that the limit when $k \to \infty$ does not resemble the correct position. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

The first equation gives us three useful pieces of information:

1. the force is constant (otherwise $F(t)$ would have been written),
2. the initial position is $0$.
3. the initial speed is $0$.

Assuming this remains true, the acceleration is given by

$$\frac{d^2p(t)}{dt^2}=\frac F{m_0-qt},$$
so we integrate twice on time, which leads to the solution by @Tom-Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's second law accommodates changing mass as well. Mass variation happens all the time for a rocket whose mass reduces with time. You should consider the momentum change for:

$ m v = m \dfrac{dx}{dt}$ ( assuming the path represented by $x$) .

$ F = \dfrac  {d(m v)}{dt} = \dot m \; v + m \dot v $...etc.